Find a lower bound of a function defined by integral
Let us define the function
$$F(x) = x\int_x^\infty \frac{e^{-y^2/4}}{y^3}dy$$
defined on an interval $[C, +\infty]$, where $C > 0$. I would like to bound this function from above and below by two functions $q_1(x), q_2(x)$ such that $q_1(x), q_2(x) \to 0$ for $x \to \infty$:
$$c_1q_1(x)\le F(x)\le c_2q_2(x) \quad \text{on }[C, +\infty],$$
for $c_1, c_2 > 0.$ Concerning the upper bound, we get
\begin{align}
x\int_x^\infty \frac{e^{-y^2/4}}{y^3}dy &\le \frac{1}{x^2}\int_x^\infty e^{-y^2/4}dy\\
&\le \frac{1}{x^2}\int_0^\infty e^{-y^2/4}dy = \frac{c_2}{x^2}.
\end{align}
Therefore we can take $q_2(x) = 1/x^2$.
However, I struggle to find the function $q_1$. Clearly one has to consider a function decaying faster than $1/x^2$ as otherwise
$$\frac{c_1}{x^2} \le x\int_x^\infty \frac{e^{-y^2/4}}{y^3}dy \quad \Leftrightarrow \quad 0 < c_1 \le x^3\int_x^\infty \frac{e^{-y^2/4}}{y^3}dy  \le \int_x^\infty e^{-y^2/4}dy \to 0 $$
as $x \to \infty$, which is a contradiction. I tried $1/x^3$, which leads to
$$ c_1 \le x^4\int_x^\infty \frac{e^{-y^2/4}}{y^3}dy =: G(x)$$
and I'm not quite sure if this $G(x)$ converges to $0$ as $x \to \infty$. Any idea how to continue from here? Can we get a slower decay than $q_1(x) = 1/x^3$ (if this works)?

Why not take $q_1=q_2=F$? Or do you just want to show that $F(x)\to0$? If so, you can use $\frac1{y^3}\le y$ and an easy antiderivative of $y\mapsto y,\mathrm e^{-y^2/4}$.

We will get optimal estimates as $q_1(x)=q_2(x)=x^{-3}e^{-x^2/4}.$ Morevoer $c_1=2^{-3}(1-e^{-3C^2/4}),$ $c_2=2.$
The upper bound can be done as follows $$ x\int\limits_x^\infty y^{-3}e^{-y^2/4}\,dy= x\int\limits_x^\infty y^{-4}(ye^{-y^2/4})\,dy\\ \le x^{-3}\int\limits_x^\infty ye^{-y^2/4}\,dy=2x^{-3}e^{-x^2/4}$$ Concerning the lower bound  we have $$ x\int\limits_x^\infty y^{-3}e^{-y^2/4}\,dy\ge  x\int\limits_x^{2x}y^{-3}e^{-y^2/4}\,dy\\=x\int\limits_x^{2x} y^{-4}(ye^{-y^2/4})\,dy \ge  2^{-4}x^{-3}\int\limits_x^{2x} ye^{-y^2/4}\,dy\\ =2^{-3}x^{-3}[e^{-x^2/4}-e^{-x^2}]=2^{-3}x^{-3}e^{-x^2/4}[1-e^{-3x^2/4}]\ge 2^{-3}(1-e^{-3C^2/4})x^{-3}e^{-x^2/2}$$

Let me start by answering your question: it's not possible to get a lower bound for $F(x)$ with a decay slower than $1/x^3$. This is a consequence of the following upper bound for $F(x)$, which is stronger than the one derived in the OP:
$$
F(x)=x\int_x^\infty \frac{e^{-y^2/4}}{y^3}dy<xe^{-x^2/4}\int_x^\infty \frac{dy}{y^3}
=\frac{e^{-x^2/4}}{2x}. \tag{1}
$$
As a matter of fact, the above inequality implies that a lower bound of $F(x)$ must decay faster than any negative power of $x$ as $x\to\infty$.
Having said that, let's derive a lower bound for $F(x)$:
$$
F(x)=x\int_x^\infty \frac{e^{-y^2/4}}{y^3}dy>x\int_x^{x+1}\frac{e^{-y^2/4}}{y^3}dy
>\frac{xe^{-(x+1)^2/4}}{(x+1)^3} \tag{2}.
$$
